# Camel check route has data

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to have a route not start if another route has in-flight exchanges within the last second.  Is their a way to get that information off from the Exchange?  I don't see it digging around the route.  Do I need to make a jmx call?

If so I will make a damn call to jolokia ... lol

Thanks

Chris

---

Solution as mentioned by Claus

`int num = exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository().size("myrouteid");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the inflight repository to know what the current inflights are. But you cannot get stats from the past.

You can access this using Java API and JMX as well.